sql column shift based on W_number
Input:

Output:

i want to write a generic mysql query which can convert input table to output table
basically value is being shifted based on w_number
the tables are just example,I need a query which can shift column up to 60.
i tried to build some logic in order to get query like this which seems to work
    SELECT 
        w_number,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_1
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_7
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_6
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_5
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_4
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_3
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_2
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_1,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_2
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_1
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_7
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_6
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_5
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_4
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_3
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_2,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_3
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_2
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_1
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_7
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_6
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_5
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_4
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_3,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_4
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_3
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_2
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_1
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_7
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_6
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_5
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_4,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_5
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_4
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_3
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_2
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_1
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_7
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_6
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_5,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_6
             WHEN w_number > 1 AND w_number <= 7 THEN 
                CASE WHEN w_number = 2 THEN value_5
                     WHEN w_number = 3 THEN value_4
                     WHEN w_number = 4 THEN value_3
                     WHEN w_number = 5 THEN value_2
                     WHEN w_number = 6 THEN value_1
                     WHEN w_number = 7 THEN value_7
                     ELSE NULL END
             ELSE NULL END AS value_6,
        CASE WHEN w_number = 1 THEN value_7
             ELSE NULL END AS value_7
    FROM your_table_name
    ORDER BY w_number;


by shift I think you mean pivot in which case research mysql pivot and mysql dynamic pivot.

Of note - Anyone using darkmode can't read your pic example.

what is the MySql version?

MySql latest version

See example.

Aggregate columns value1...valueN to json_array
Take new values from array by calculated index ar[i].
Json_array index base is 0. So we use idx=w_number-1.
Formula is (7-idx+0)%7 for value_1,(7-idx+1)%7 for value_2.
If you have another number of value_N columns, change 7 by appropriate value.
Output values have text type, cast if necessary.

Test data updated with rows like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], where we can explicitly see shift of values by w_number.
select *
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+0)%7,']'))value_1
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+1)%7,']'))value_2
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+2)%7,']'))value_3
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+3)%7,']'))value_4
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+4)%7,']'))value_5
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+5)%7,']'))value_6
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(ar,concat('$[',(7-idx+6)%7,']'))value_7
from(
select id,w_number,json_array(value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5,value_6,value_7) ar
  ,w_number-1 idx
from test
)jsa

Output is (w_number - w_n)



id
w_n
ar
idx
value_1
value_2
value_3
value_4
value_5
value_6
value_7




1
5
[10, 20, null, null, null, null, null]
4
null
null
null
null
10
20
null


2
4
[null, 50, 60, 70, null, null, null]
3
null
null
null
null
50
60
70


3
2
[null, 90, null, 110, null, null, null]
1
null
null
90
null
110
null
null


4
2
[null, null, 30, 40, null, null, null]
1
null
null
null
30
40
null
null


5
1
[50, 60, 70, 90, null, null, null]
0
50
60
70
90
null
null
null


6
3
[90, 100, 110, 120, null, null, null]
2
null
null
90
100
110
120
null


7
5
[null, 50, 60, 70, null, null, null]
4
70
null
null
null
null
50
60


8
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7


9
2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1
7
1
2
3
4
5
6


10
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
2
6
7
1
2
3
4
5


11
4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3
5
6
7
1
2
3
4


12
5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
4
4
5
6
7
1
2
3


13
6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5
3
4
5
6
7
1
2


14
7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6
2
3
4
5
6
7
1


15
8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7



{Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/rbQW_Xbf)
